# Count same types element in array mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
{
      _id:1, members: [
        {
            name:"John",
            status:"A"  
        },
        {
            name:"Alex",
            status:"D"  
        },
        {
            name:"Jack",
            status:"A"  
        },
        {
            name:"Robin",
            status:"D"  
        }
    ]}
```

That is `Channel document`.

Now I need to `count` all elements in members array where `status equal to 'A'`.

For example the above doc has 2 members with `status 'A'`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `db.collectionname.find({"members.status":"A"}).count()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here Is your Json file

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("575915653b3cc43fca1fca4c"),
    "members" : [
        {
            "name" : "John",
            "status" : "A"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Alex",
            "status" : "D"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Jack",
            "status" : "A"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Robin",
            "status" : "D"
        }
    ]
}
```

> And you want to the count of all elements in members array where
>   status equal to 'A'.
>
> you have to try this one to find out your count

```
db.CollectionName.aggregate([{
    "$project": {
        "members": {
            "$filter": {
                "input": "$members",
                "as": "mem",
                "cond": {
                    "$eq": ["$$mem.status", "A"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    "$project": {
        "membersize": {
            "$size": "$members"
        }
    }
}]).pretty()
```

> And you found your answer is like that { "_id" :
>   **ObjectId("575915653b3cc43fca1fca4c"), "membersize" : 2 }**
>
> try this one for old version......

```
db.CollectionName.aggregate([{"$unwind":"$members"},{"$match":{"members.status":"A"}},{"$group":{_id:"$_id","memberscount":{"$sum":1}}}]).pretty()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("575915653b3cc43fca1fca4c"), "memberscount" : 2 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mongodb-count](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/) to achieve the desired result.

> Returns the count of documents that would match a find() query. The db.collection.count() method does not perform the find() operation but instead counts and returns the number of results that match a query.

So your query will be

```
var recordcount = db.collName.count({"members.status":"A"});
```

Now `recordCount` will be number of records that matches `{"members.status":"A"}` query.

Answer (score -1):

> Here Is your Json file

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("575915653b3cc43fca1fca4c"),
    "members" : [
        {
            "name" : "John",
            "status" : "A"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Alex",
            "status" : "D"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Jack",
            "status" : "A"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Robin",
            "status" : "D"
        }
    ]
}
```

> And you want to the count of all elements in members array where
>   status equal to 'A'.
>
> you have to try this one to find out your count

```
db.CollectionName.aggregate([{
    "$project": {
        "members": {
            "$filter": {
                "input": "$members",
                "as": "mem",
                "cond": {
                    "$eq": ["$$mem.status", "A"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    "$project": {
        "membersize": {
            "$size": "$members"
        }
    }
}]).pretty()
```

> And you found your answer is like that { "_id" :
>   **ObjectId("575915653b3cc43fca1fca4c"), "membersize" : 2 }**

Comment: Thanks, But my mongodb version is 3.0.7 and can'nt update. So is there any other solution with this mongodb version.

Comment: try this one then db.CollectionName.aggregate([{"$unwind":"$members"},{"$match":{"members.status":"A"}},{"$group":{_id:"$_id","memberscount":{"$sum":1}}}]).pretty()